# Selecting specified query from multiple select statement inside a single stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, stored-procedures

Good Day everyone!

I've been searching everywhere on how to get a specified query using if-else statement inside a single stored procedure but still no luck on how to achieve those function.

Here's the T-Sql

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[getHistoryList]
@documentNo varchar(150)=null,
@material varchar(150)=null,
@action varchar(10)=null
as

declare @query nvarchar(max);

if (@action = null)
begin
set @query = 'select top 50 * from s_HistoryList order by documentDate desc'
exec sp_executesql @statement=@query
end 

else if (@action = 'search')
begin
set @query = 'select * from s_HistoryList where documentNo like %'+@documentNo+'% or materialName like %'+@material+'%'
exec sp_executesql @statement=@query
end
go
```

When exec command is called, it only return Command(s) completed successfully instead the value/table of the selected command. Since the @action is null, it should return the following query and when @ action is supplied with value, it should return the 2nd query.

When if-else statement is removed, it returns the first query but there's no means of accessing the 2nd query.

I saw this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601480/multiple-queries-is-single-stored-procedure).

Thank you and I appreaciate any help that this post can get.

Comment: `@action = null` could never be true. Try `IF @action IS NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to print the variable to the value of the variable @action.
Eg:

```
begin
set @query = 'select * from s_HistoryList where documentNo like %'+@documentNo+'% or materialName like %'+@material+'%'
exec sp_executesql @statement=@query
print 'Below is the value of @action'
print @action
end


A point i would make is that NULL comparison wouldnt work with = sign. 

if (@action = null) to be changed to 
if (@action IS NULL)
```

Comment: I tried changing the '=' sign in @ action into 'IS'. The output is returns the expected table. Thank you for pointing out.

The problem is, the 2nd query. I would like to return the table that the sp_executesql makes, not the value that the @ action have. The output result is still the command completed message.

Comment: To do that you would remove the sp_executesql portion and write the query directly (ie not in string limiters)

Comment: @JohnMichael SQL injection alert. What if someone passes through `@documentNo='''; DROP TABLE; SELECT '''`

Comment: @Charlieface, I have end-to-end encryption and data sanitation for passing data and accessing this stored procedure since there's a possibility of injection even when using stored procedure.

Comment: @JohnMichael That's the wrong way to go about it. You don't sanitize, you parameterize. Even dynamic can be parameterized